# Can pain be exquisite without masochism?

Tags: meaning

Can pain be 'exquisite' without being masochistic?

Comment: Yes, but any answer would be beyond the bounds of this site. This is not an English question.

Comment: The dual meanings of 'exquisite' are surely on-topic?

Comment: @Michael Harvey... My thinking is that "exquisite" would be a matter of opinion, whether positive or negative.

Comment: I suppose that if I had been in a car crash, and my leg was half off, and a bookish doctor, trying to decide if I needed morphine, asked me how exquisite the pain was, I'd probably answer "Very!"

Comment: A recent experience of pain (a particularly intense dental abscess) taught me that pain can reach such a crescendo that the nerve (or neuron) can no longer (it seems) transmit the signal to the brain. I would call that experience 'exquisite' as there is a point where pain suddenly stops (susprisingly) and there is momentary relief. Before the signal decreases and pain is felt again. I believe this may be what the word 'exquisite' means in the context of pain.

Comment: My concept of "exquisite pain" is the extreme pain one gets from a thigh wound in a combat situation. If there is intense pain, generally there is no serious damage. On the other hand, if one's leg folds up with no great sensation, there would be a good chance of serious bone and, or, nerve damage.

Comment: My thought would be the "exquisite pain is that which reminds you that you are alive," like the burning of one's legs when climbing a mountain.  I don't think one has to be masochistic for that.  It can remind you that you are alive in a truly nuanced and beautiful way... and you can still never want to have to be reminded that way again, thank you very much! ;-)

Comment: See [definition 2-B](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exquisite): *acute, intense -- exquisite pain*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pain can indeed be exquisite with no implication of masochism. The adjective 'exquisite' has two meanings. One is more commonly used - "very beautiful and delicate" and might be used about a piece of sculpture, china, jewellery, etc. The other more literary meaning is used about strong feelings, pleasant or unpleasant. An exquisite pain is a severe pain, and not at all pleasant to experience, unless, of course, one is a masochist.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/exquisite)

Comment: I've had a couple of kidney stones where I would have used the adjective "exquisite" to describe the pain -- somehow it just fits the intense, highly focused pain.  (Of course, the morphine injection I received when I had my first encounter was also "exquisite" -- somehow the total annihilation of the pain and the ensuing dream-like sensation is almost worth the pain.)